# C++\CLI LNK Error 2019 & 2028 with Included .h and .lib (Linker finds those Files) [Wrapper]

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper, linker-errors

I have a problem with this code, writing a wrapper function from an existing .lib (CryptoLib.lib):

mycode.ccp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "CryptoLib.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "CryptoLib.lib")
#pragma managed(pop)

using namespace System;//This is a C++-CLI project.

__declspec(dllexport) void Encrypt(unsigned char *Data, unsigned char *RandomNr)
{
   CryptoLib_Encrypt(Data, RandomNr);
}
```

cryptolib.h

```
#ifndef _CRYPTOLIB_H_
#define _CRYPTOLIB_H_

#define PUBLIC
//This procedure is written in c++ code
extern void CryptoLib_Encrypt(unsigned char *Data, unsigned char *RandomNr);

#endif /* _CRYPTOLIB_H_ */
```

I have linked the cryptolib.h and the cryptolib, but i get still the 
"unresolved token Cryptolib_Encrypt"
and the
"unresolved external symbol Cryptolib_Encrypt"
Errors.

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks for helping

Exact Error-messages:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000006) "void __cdecl CryptoLib_Encrypt(unsigned char *,unsigned char *)" (?CryptoLib_Encrypt@@$$FYAXPAE0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Encrypt(unsigned char *,unsigned char *)" (?Encrypt@@$$FYAXPAE0@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CryptoLib_Encrypt(unsigned char *,unsigned char *)" (?CryptoLib_Encrypt@@$$FYAXPAE0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Encrypt(unsigned char *,unsigned char *)" (?Encrypt@@$$FYAXPAE0@Z)


error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

The `Dumpbin.exe /exports` comand line
returns just
[image: Dumpbin.exe /exports]

But i still added the C/C++ Additional Include Directory in Configuration Properties/"C/C++"/General and the Additional Dependencies (`Cryptolib.lib`) in Configuation Properties/Linker/Input

Comment: The #include "stdafx.h" directive must be the *first* line in your code.  Note the warning you get for this.

Comment: It seems like it only has to be the first #include

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment (lib, "CryptoLib.lib")
#include "stdafx.h"
```

This is wrong.  The compiler will go looking for the stdafx.h #include directive and **ignores** anything it finds before that.  So it will completely ignore your #pragma comment directive.  The linker will therefore *not* link CryptoLib.lib and you'll indeed get this linker error.  Using #pragma once in a .cpp file does not make sense.

Another problem is that you appear to compile this code with /clr in effect, we can tell from the *using* statement.  The compiler cannot tell that your function is a __cdecl function, it will assume the default and that's __clrcall when managed code compilation is enabled.  You have to be explicit about it, like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"          // First line in file!
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "CryptoLib.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "CryptoLib.lib")
#pragma managed(pop)
```

There's yet another possible problem with the function declaration, it isn't clear whether that function was compiled with a C compiler or a C++ compiler.  A C++ compiler will *decorate* the function name.  If it was actually compiled with a C compiler then you have to tell the compiler about that:

```
#ifndef _CRYPTOLIB_H_
#define _CRYPTOLIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void __cdecl CryptoLib_Encrypt(unsigned char *Data, unsigned char *RandomNr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _CRYPTOLIB_H_ */
```

Note the usage of `extern "C"`, it disables name decoration.  If you cannot or should not edit this header file then you can cram the extern "C" {} in your .cpp file, surrounding the #include.

If you still have trouble then post the **exact** linker error message as well what you see when you run `Dumpbin.exe /exports` on the DLL from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: I changed the first lines of Wrapper.cpp and i still get the same Errors.
And i think the lib is written in c++ code, because i didn't create the header myself.
Thanks for trying

Comment: The names got the C++ decoration, note the @@$$FYAXPAE0@Z in the name. I specifically warned about that.  You really do need to run dumpbin.exe so you know what these symbols *really* look like.  Please avoid taking shortcuts.

Comment: I have no DLL, i sould create one depending on the lib

Is that possible?

Comment: If this is a static link library and not the import library for a DLL then you are liable to have a lot more problems, they can typically only work when they were built with the exact same compiler as you are using.  You could dumpbin.exe /all instead to see External names.  But it is pretty likely that you'll need to contact the library owner and get an update so it will work with your compiler.